# Rationale for range restriction of IEEE-754 compound function

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

The IEEE Std 754-2008 lists in Table 9.1
the recommended function `compound(x,n) = (1+x)^n`, with real x, integer n (where `^` is the power operator). 
The domain is specified as `x in [-1, +infinity]` and `n in Z`.
The function shall signal an invalid operation exception for x < -1.

Is there some good/known but not listed reason for the range restriction? Mathematically (1+x)^n is well-defined for all x != -1 (and even for x = -1 if n > 0).

Comment: Since the email archive for the IEEE Std 754-2008 working group seems to have been removed from public internet access, we can only hope that one of the several committee members who are also on Stackoverflow remembers the rationale. My educated *guess* is that the domain restriction arises directly from the common definition `compound (r,n) = exp (n * log1p (r))`.

Comment: @njuffa yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, ln(1 + x) is used, and ln(1 + -1) is undefined mathematically.  Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (they discuss this using e vs. 2).

Comment: "Internally, ln(1 + x) is used, and ln(1 + -1) is undefined mathematically." --> OK, yet OP's issue is about `x < -1`, not so much about `x == -1`.  Perhaps `ln(1 + a_value_less_than_negative_1)` being undefined with `ln()` is the issue.